# How to link each picture in a picture gallery in Wordpress to different URLs?

Tags: wordpress

I have a picture gallery on my Wordpresspage with different pictures in it and I want to link to a different URL for each picture if the user clicks on a specific picture. How can I do this? In Wordpress is just the option to link to one single URL for the hole picture gallery but not for a specific link for each picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WP when you are creating a gallery, your choices are either to link the image to the attachment page or the media file.

But if you want each individual image to be a custom link you would need to add a new function to WP. And to do that the easiest way is to use a plugin called *Gallery Custom Links*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I habe searched on some german forums but nobody had an answer ... do you know why two people downvoted my question? Did I made any mistakes with my question?

Comment: They downvoted because this site is for questions regarding code. Not general questions regarding WP. A simple Google search would have given you an answer. If you asked on how to code that and given examples of the codes you tried then your question would not have been downvoted.

Comment: Okay where can I ask general questions aboud wordpress? I have searched for the problem on google but I did not find an answer.

Comment: You can ask here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions  However please note that that link is also for code/development questions. 

You can still ask your questions on StackOverflow but make sure you at least give a code attempt you tried. For general questions your best bet is Google. For code questions you can post them here or on that link.